# Remove solution from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution

**What I tried:** I delete the projects attached to the solution file and delete the associated .sln file.

I also remove site region from IISExpress\config\applicationhost however at each try it creates the solution file as Nameofexsolutionfile(2).

**Question:**

Is there a way to **permanently** remove, edit or view solution files attached to Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I have the same problem and I found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20078271/2340783