# Number displayed after a new Web Site project's name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I deleted an old ASP.NET Web Application project called `nPower.Ignition.WebResponsive` from my solution in Visual Studio, but when I added a new Web Site project in the same spot, I saw `(1)` appended at the end of my desired name. I tried to delete and recreate a few more times, and now I'm to the point where it looks like this in my solution explorer, with `(3)` appended on the end of my desired name!

[image]

So... I pretty much know what caused this, but not how to fix it.

Is Visual Studio remembering that I used to have a project with that name in my solution, even though I've deleted it, and trying to avoid a conflict by giving it a different name? Is there a way I can get rid of the number appended at the end? I understand it probably won't make much of a difference from a programming standpoint if I leave the name as is, but it looks quite sloppy!

Comment: My speculation is that inside the solution folder _on the hard drive_ the folders for the deleted projects still exist.  When you try to create a new project, it detects that the folder name it taken, so is adding an incrementing number to find a unique name.  _If_ I'm right, simply deleting these folders should fix it.

Comment: Well there isn't any old folder for the deleted projects--I manually deleted them. But yeah, that was what I thought may have caused it.

Comment: Feels funny to do this to my own question but, it's a duplicate of [Completely deleting Visual Studio website solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067377/completely-deleting-visual-studio-website-solutions)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This occurs because each time you create a Web Site project using IIS Express, VS adds a new entry to IIS Express' applicationhost.config (`C:\Users\YourName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`).  Each website needs to be unique, so VS will append and increment the number following the name.

To get rid of this, you need to clear out the conflicting entries in the applicationhost.config file.

In more recent versions of Visual Studio, the `applicationhost.config` file is located in the `.vs\config` folder under the solution file.

Comment: Yep! That's got to be it. And I just realized my question is a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067377/completely-deleting-visual-studio-website-solutions

Comment: I actually deleted the C:\Users\YourName\Documents\IISExpress  and when I opened my website  the first time, the (1) appeared in the file name

Comment: Also check your project applicationhost.config file in .vs/config.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34716590/1467810

Comment: 4 YEARS LATER (10-Mar-2018) - Using Visual Studio 2017 v15.6.1 -- this solution does not work -- there is NO matching entry in the C:\Users\YourName\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config file -- now what?

Comment: @bdcoder the applicationhost.config file now exists for each solution under .vs\config.  However, we still get the extra (1) showing up, so I opened a feedback ticket.  Feel free to vote it up: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212349/default-name-for-website-project-is-website11-even.html

Comment: @Jimmy - Yes -- you can edit the applicationhost.config file to get rid of the (#) that is appended to the website name, see my posted solution at: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212337/number-displayed-after-website-name.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that when you delete it from VS, some part is remaining on your hard disk, either the SLN file or the folder.  So, when you create a new one, it sees it already exists and adds the number.

Answer (score 0):

After having my computer's hard disk replaced by a SSD (with the use of a disk cloning tool), my VS 2015 weirdly stopped executing automatically as administrator, and since the defined website port was 1000, it no more had permission to use that port. Hence, it was always creating an identical entry in $(SolutionDir).vs\config\applicationhost.config, just to set a new port (above 50000). Only when I configured it to start as administrator again, I was able to open the solution without having the website renamed to "___(1)".