# How to get Visual Studio to STOP appending useless numbers to my project names?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I am building an ASP.NET website with Visual Studio, sometimes I will need to delete the project and rewrite it, sometimes because I have decided to do something very new which would require a rewrite, and sometimes due to bugs where the easiest fix/workaround involves "starting fresh".

But there is one thing that Visual Studio does that really gets on my nerves.

When I *delete* all website and project files and then create a new website with the same name, Visual Studio then decides to append (1) to the end of the website/project name, or (2) or (3). So instead of my project being Assignment Site, it then becomes AssignmentSite (1).

I've searched my entire computer for 'AssignmentSite (1)' and there are never any results. But it still knows and still appends this useless junk to my filename. How do I get it to stop it?

Comment: Start using source control (May i recommend Git?)

Comment: Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067377/completely-deleting-visual-studio-website-solutions

Comment: Or stop using web site "projects" and start using Web Application Projects, which are real projects and don't have such bizarre behavior.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm not sure what to call them to be honest because Visual Studio refers to them as different things in different places. What I _create_ is File > New > New Website > ... So whatever they are. :)

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for the recommendation. I will have a look at Git.

Comment: Right, that's what to not use. Use File->New Project and choose one of the Web Application Project templates.

Comment: @JohnSaunders But the _type_ of websites I create are not available in there. :-/

Comment: What kind of web site can you not create as a web application project?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ASP.NET Website (Razor v3) and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Website but mainly the first one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Unless I am mistaken. But the few times I have gone through the steps in New Project > Web App Proj. I have only been given the option to create an MVC type website.

Comment: @JohnSaunders After thinking about it for a few hours, I decided to check out 'Web Application Project' that you mentioned, and see what kind of things have been added since last time I went there. I then found ASP.NET 5 template - I had no idea I had that here. So thanks, I've been meaning to have a play around with it for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason VS thinks the website still exists is because it's looking
>   at the IIS Express applicationhost.config file (under
>   %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config).
>   Your old website is still registered under IIS Express, so VS
>   generates a unique name for the new one.

Source:
[Completely deleting Visual Studio website solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067377/completely-deleting-visual-studio-website-solutions)

Comment: No problem.
if it helped, marked it as solved so other will know the solution.

Comment: Yep, was just waiting for the timer :)